# 'iftex.sty' not found

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex

I've been having this problem . My system is Windows 10 The iftex package required XeTeX, PDFTeX or LuaTeX. My Texmaker has XeLaTeX, PDFLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. How can I add these other compilation methods (so I can use the europasscv class)? I also installed TeXworks and used the LuaTeX option there, then I get a "can't find the format file `miktex-luatex.fmt'!" - EDIT:this was fixed when I ran luatex -ini luatex.ini They all (XeTeX, PDFTeX or LuaTeX) give the following error; ! Undefined control sequence. l.1 \documentclass [english,a4paper]{europasscv}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! From the error message ("Undefined control sequence `\documentclass`") it looks like you are running plain TeX (`pdftex`, `xetex`, `luatex`). Try running LaTeX instead (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`).

Comment: Did you install the `iftex` package? I don't think it's installed by default.

Comment: I get an error saying iftex package could not be installed. Weirdly I tried it on another computer and somehow got it working - I think it didn't work at first then later installed fine. I took a pic of the directory and what files I need. I hope I can download these somewhere but they were not available in a zip file I downloaded from this location https://ctan.org/pkg/iftex?lang=en

Comment: I looked at the log file and it gave this : Info: ="="get host by name failed in tcp_connect()""